# Term used for the number of items in a singular or plural noun or sentence

Tags: grammatical-number, subjects

Can anyone confirm the name of the term used 
for the number of items in the terms singular, 
plural, etc.?

Does singular or plural indicate the *cardinality* 
of a part of the sentence, or is there a more 
appropriate word for the term *cardinality*?

E.G. When "We went to the store" has a plural subject, does plural
refer to the *cardinality* of the subject,
or is a different word used to refer to the 
fact that the count is more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you are looking for is *plurality*.

> **1** the fact or state of being plural : *some languages add an extra syllable to mark plurality.* (NOAD)

Answer (score 4):

In linguistics, **singular, dual, multal,** and **plural** are all types of [grammatical number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number). (As an interesting side note, in English, the grammatical category of **plural** doesn't always correspond to the natural English meaning of plural (e.g., *1.0 pens*).)